# What are the accountsKeychainImport entries in Keychain Access?

Tags: macos, keychain

I have noted some accountsKeychainImport files in the macOS Keychain Access application:

[image: accountsKeychainImport]

A Google search for `accountsKeychainImport` brought up **ZERO** hits (and lot's of hits for „accounts Keychain Import” which where not at all helpful).

Does anyone know where these entries come from and how to delete them?

Comment: Could it be related to this https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/368138/30895 ?

Comment: Indeed it is. You could have made that an answer for a full upvote and correct answer. The only difference is the naming of the zombi keychain which is the reason why Google didn't come up any results.

Comment: The other question is about a spurious “accountsKeychain**Export**” after exporting developer profiles from Xcode (which I can reproduce). I did not get a “ accountsKeychain**Import**” after exporting or importing a developer profile, therefore I do not yet see if that is the same issue.